# Checksum error for ubuntu-14.04.5-server-amd64.iso download with Packer

Tags: ubuntu, checksum, iso

I'm having the following error on the checksum key: `virtualbox-iso: Error downloading: checksums didn't match expected: dd54dc8cfc2a655053d19813c2f9aa9f`.
I've took the key from ubuntu release site. An idea about the correct key to set as reference?

Answer (score 0):

the key used was of md5sums. The type of checksum performed is of sha256sums so the correct key (found on ubuntu site:http://releases.ubuntu.com/trusty/) was: `dde07d37647a1d2d9247e33f14e91acb10445a97578384896b4e1d985f754cc1`

other sha256 key of other isos are the following:

```
f5ce20686a2f3201f04a309d04171ee15757f00954b33b87f3f1d36b3b0f5356 *ubuntu-14.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso
24156b487290b26f150f58a53efab0cf8572e6ad6302446b98afe7b4b70a8e8f *ubuntu-14.04.5-desktop-i386.iso
dde07d37647a1d2d9247e33f14e91acb10445a97578384896b4e1d985f754cc1 *ubuntu-14.04.5-server-amd64.iso
6071b0844ecbb8aa9a246b15c7aa20e798d42ed5b41c1b71aaea1f4283985ba4 *ubuntu-14.04.5-server-i386.iso
bc3b20ad00f19d0169206af0df5a4186c61ed08812262c55dbca3b7b1f1c4a0b *wubi.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using packer, You should consider sharing your `<server-name>.json` file located on packer-templates folder so that we can give you more accurate answer.

Either way, try updating your box name to `ubuntu-14.04.5-server-amd64` and try using this `iso-checksum=dde07d37647a1d2d9247e33f14e91acb10445a97578384896b4e1d985f754cc1`